# Get RDF triples about an OWL Class in Jena

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, semantic-web, owl

I am tring to make an OWL verbaliser to transform an ontology into human-readable texts.For the beginning I want to take an OWL class and to obtain all statements about it.

For example given the OWL class "WhiteBurgundy" :

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="WhiteBurgundy">
  <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Burgundy" />
    <owl:Class rdf:about="#WhiteWine" />
  </owl:intersectionOf>
</owl:Class>
```

I want to obtain the triples:

`("WhiteBurgundy", "isfrom" , ""#Burgundy")                                            .`

`("WhiteBurgundy", "isa" , ""#WhiteWine")                                              .`

or something similar

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have only mentioned a class, because you need to also know about the properties of that the classes are defined through to be able to make the verbaliser. If you read the whole OWL file and then extract what you need, that probably would be more informative. For example, I tried to extract both the names of the classes and the properties:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create the reasoning model using the base
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
    String file = "Ontology" + File.separator + "pizza.owl";

    InputStream in;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        model.read(in, "RDF/XML");
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // or any windows path


    // Create a new query
    String queryString =        
            "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "+
                    "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>  "+
                    "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>  "+
                    "select distinct * "+
                    "where { "+
                    "?s a owl:Class."+
                    "?s rdfs:subClassOf  ?o ."+
                    "?o owl:onProperty  ?y ."+
                    "?o owl:someValuesFrom|owl:allValuesFrom  ?z ."+

                    "} \n ";
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

    // Execute the query and obtain results
    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
    ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect();

    // Output query results    
    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);

}
```

However, this is much easier done in [OWL API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net). You can easily extract everything. Jena is not as powerful when dealing with OWL files.